# C/C++ macro parameter containing dot (member access operator)

Tags: c++, c, arguments, c-preprocessor, member-access

How can one use in C/C++ macro parameter containing dot (member access operator)?

Example:

```cpp
#define M(obj,y) obj.y##x
struct S { struct {int x;} c; int x; };
S s;
s.c.x = 1;
s.x = 2;
M(s,)   // works, 2 (resolves to s.x)
M(s,c.) // error: pasting formed '.x', an invalid preprocessing token
```

How can one make `M(s,c.)` to resolve to `s.c.x` ?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you using C or C++?  If you are using C++ I would suggest ditching the macro and making a template function.

Comment: Macros tend to make code harder to read, understand and maintain. Especially macros like the one you want to make. Please try to avoid them.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! Still, is it possible to do?

Comment: You probably need another layer of indirection like what is done with concat macros.  I'm not a macro pro though so it might not help.

Comment: It's okay to have whitespace on either side (or both) of the `.`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The token pasting operator `##` requires its two operands to be valid preprocessing tokens, and yields a single preprocessing token. It is often used to concatenate two identifiers into a single identifier.

What you are trying to do here is not token pasting. Instead, you are seeking to create expressions like `s.x` or `s.c.x` where the `x` part is always a single token. Therefore, the `##` operator should not be used. Instead, you can just do this:

```
#define M(obj, y) obj.y x
```

When you try to use the `##` operator, the preprocessor tries to combine the last token in the argument `y` with the token `x`. In `c.`, the `.` is a token, so the result is `.x`, which is not a valid token. Rather, `.x` is only valid as a sequence of two tokens.

Comment: This is also applicable if you are using the arrow operator ->